# LISP--Passing a structure component, not the value of the component

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I’m having a problem passing components of a structure in LISP.  I want to pass the component, as opposed to the value of the component.

To illustrate my objective, let’s say I have an instance of a structure, `node`.  Node has the components, `farmer`, `fox`, `goose`, and `straw`.  I’d like the function to be flexible, so I can pass any of these components to a function.

```
(defun pass-comp (node object)
  (setf object 1)
  node)

(pass-comp (node (node-fox node))
(write (node-fox node))
—> 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Lisp, all arguments are always passed by value.
If you want to modify the content of a structure you pass, you can do it by specifying what you want modified:

```
(defstruct node farmer fox goose straw)
(defparameter *node* (make-node :fox 3))
(defun change-slot (object slot-name new-value)
  (setf (slot-value object slot-name) new-value))
(change-slot *node* 'fox 7)
(change-slot *node* 'goose 23)
*node*
==> #S(NODE :FARMER NIL :FOX 3 :GOOSE 23 :STRAW NIL)
```

Note that even though the standard does *not* require
[`slot-value`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_slt_va.htm) to work on
[`structure-object`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_stu_ob.htm), the
above code works on all CL implementations.

If you want your code to be [conforming](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/01_eb.htm), you should pass a *setter*:

```
(defun change-slot (object setter new-value)
  (funcall setter new-value object))
(change-slot *node* #'(setf node-farmer) 6)
*node*
==> #S(NODE :FARMER 6 :FOX 3 :GOOSE 23 :STRAW NIL)
```

This, alas, is not guaranteed to work either [because](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defstr.htm):

> it is implementation-dependent whether the ability to write the slot is implemented by a setf function or a setf expander.

Thus you need to create your own setter:

```
(change-slot *node* (lambda (straw node) (setf (node-straw node) straw)) 11)
*node*
==> #S(NODE :FARMER 6 :FOX 3 :GOOSE 23 :STRAW 11)
```

Comment: The first example works well form my purpose in CCL.

Answer (score 2):

Structures are in standard CL very static - for example the effects of redefining a structure is undefined. It's also undefined if we can access a structure by slot name. What exists are slot reader functions and support for using them with `setf`.

Let's say we have a structure type:

```
(defstruct node fox)
```

Then when we want to change a component of the structure, we need to pass a function which sets that component:

```
(defun pass-comp (node setter-fn)
  (funcall setter-fn node 1)
  node)
```

We can then pass in a setter function:

```
(let ((my-node (make-node)))
  (pass-comp my-node
             (lambda (node new)
               (setf (node-fox node) new)))
  (node-fox my-node))
```